# Delaying Knockout's visible binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a shopping cart. When it's empty, I want to show a div with a "Empty" message. When it has items in it, I want to show a div with the items. Currently, I have something like this...

```
<div style="display: none" data-bind="visible: items().length == 0">Empty</div>
<div style="display: none" data-bind="visible: items().length > 0">Not Empty</div>
```

...and this...

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

Now, I'm using AJAX to load in the items which means there is an initial period of uncertainty as to if there are or aren't items in the cart. This means the page starts by showing the "Empty" div and then quickly, upon seeing that there are items, replacing it with the "Not Empty" div—a process which looks clunky on screen.

How can I suspend the `visible` function on the div until my AJAX is done and I know the item count?

One thing I thought of (seen working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b2mdvw1c/)) is to create a separate property `showEmpty`...

```
<div style="display: none" data-bind="visible: showEmpty">Empty</div>
<div style="display: none" data-bind="visible: items().length > 0">Not Empty</div>
```

...and to set it to `undefined` by default. This means `visible` won't resolve until `showEmpty` is defined. I then define it within the AJAX call...

```
self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
self.showEmpty = ko.observable(undefined);

// Fake AJAX
setTimeout(function() {
    self.items([1]);        
    self.showEmpty(self.items().length == 0);
}, 2000);
```

This 100% works but it presents a new problem: I am now *manually* updating an observable. As seen below, when I want to add or remove items to/from my array, those functions must now worry themselves with updating the `showEmpty` property.

```
self.addItem = function() {
    self.items.push(1);
    self.showEmpty(false);
};

self.removeItem = function() {
    self.items.pop();
    self.showEmpty(self.items().length == 0);
};
```

I feel like the entire purpose of KO is to avoid this kind of thing. What I would like, then, is some way to set *only* an initial delay on the resolution of the div's `visible` function. After that initial wait, I would like the `visible` function to update based on the `.length` of an observable array.

Thanks!

Comment: you could write your own binding or use an animated class.

Comment: Or just have a second variable called Loading, set that to true, and make the end of the ajax set it to false. Then just include that variable in the show requirement for either side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@pquest gave me the solution in a comment so I'm putting it here in detail for other people to see later on.

As seen in my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2mdvw1c/1/), I added a `loadingDone` observable and included a reference to it in the `visible` binding...

```
<div style="display: none" data-bind="visible: items().length == 0 && loadingDone">Empty</div>
<div style="display: none" data-bind="visible: items().length > 0">Not Empty</div>
```

In my script I was able to remove all of the manual updating...

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;    

    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.loadingDone = ko.observable(false);

    // Fake AJAX
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.items([1]);        
        self.loadingDone(true);
    }, 2000);

    self.addItem = function() {
        self.items.push(1);
    };

    self.removeItem = function() {
        self.items.pop();
    };
};
```

Nice! I still wish I could accomplish the same without adding the additional observable but this is a lot better than what I had so I'm happy.

Comment: A different approach to fixing this issue: Do not show the page/cart/whatever you deem correct UNTIL you are done loading the necessary data. This is pretty common: viewModels often have an activate method (or something similar) and the page will be hidden until the activate method is done (usually with promises for async loading). If you use this approach, you can load the cart data in your activate method and not have the problem at all. Since you will run into this issue many times, and introducing extra observables is extra housekeeping, this way you solve the problem in a generic way.

Comment: That makes sense. I ended up doing something like that in my project but didn't think about making it more generic and using it elsewhere. I will definitely go back and do something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Not enough rep to comment, sorry) Unless you absolutely HAVE to use knockout for your visibility, why not do it with jQuery instead using the .show() and .hide() functions for the div worked in to your AJAX.  Check for the observable item length at the end of your AJAX call and .show() if its greater than 0, otherwise it stays hidden.. (unless you need that "empty" message there)

Comment: The reason I'm using KO to do this is because it allows me to simply state the condition under which I want the div to be visible and then forget about it. With the jQuery approach, I have to write code to grab ID's, check their values, and then grab other ID's and run show/hide on them, etc. Thanks for the suggestion though. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add an observable, you can move setTimeout outside your viewModel and then call the ajax function that is in your ViewModel from there.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    // other code

    self.fake_ajax = function() {
    };
}

var vm = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
    vm.fake_ajax();
}, 3000);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5en0ojz/2/).

Comment: In your fiddle, notice how when you first hit RUN it shows "Cart is Empty"? That's what I am wanting to avoid because, of course, it isn't true in some cases and will confuse people. And, again, it looks bad when things load and then quickly flicker away a split second later. Thanks anyway though. :)

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood what you were asking for.